# How to obtain SVM accuracy?

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I have a SVM running to classify a huge load of feature vectors. It's been trained with around 1 million feature vectors. I use the OpenCV SVM class for that. How do I measure the accuracy of the trained SVM?

On [this page](http://www.bytefish.de/blog/using_libsvm/) I read:

`>>> pred_lbl, pred_acc, pred_val = svm_predict(c_test,d_test,m)
Accuracy = 76.6667% (46/60) (classification)`

Even though there libsvm have been used, I think OpenCV just wraps libsvm classes. Am I right? What I'm driving at is that there is maybe such a return value possible in OpenCV aswell.

As you can read on the webpage, he runs a grid search to obtain the best svm parameters. The best parameterset is obtained when accuracy is maximized (`p_acc[0]`).

Or do I have to handlabel all feature vectors to get some sort of ground truth with which i could estimate the accuracy? This would be quite alot of work and would love to avoid it.

I've also seen some similar questions here, but no clear answer to my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I think OpenCV just wraps libsvm classes" - more a re-write, based on the original libSVM code

Comment: "do I have to handlabel all feature vectors" - it for sure needs proper labels for training. what kind of labels are you using now for that ?

Comment: basically I obtain feature vectors from images and cluster those with kmeans. My algorithm desides with cluster is labeled with class 1 or 2. I want to gain some sort of online-learning, and the accuracy of the svm would also be a measurement on how good my self-labeling performs.

Comment: just saying: labels acquired from kmeans / er or any unsupervised approach are far away from 'ground truth'

Comment: i'm kinda involved in some similar project, atm (face-verification), and i'd be *very* happy, if i could get 76% acc. the way *you* do it now (not relying on ground-truth labels) -  ;)

Comment: ok ;) I would atleast love to pass the 85% acc. mark. Results look quite good so far, but I have to measure acc. first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You measure accuracy by holding back some data (not using it for training) and measuring the performance of the model on that data.

Comment: ah ok, and "measuring the performance of the model on that data" would be handlabeled data as ground truth?

Comment: You could create new data for performance measurement too if you dont want to train again. But holding back data during training allows you to automatically measure performance and retrain

Comment: you want to keep the 'train' and the 'test' set seperate to avoid bias.

Comment: You want to be very, very, sure that the test data is not included, even by duplication, in the training set.

Comment: That is just an automated holdback mechanism.